# Java scanner with ANSI Escape sequences and cursor movement displays ^R when moving cursor away and back to scanner

Tags: java, ansi-escape

I am working on a CLI Java-based SMS test messaging system and I am using ANSI Escape sequences to move the cursor. Currently, I have a scanner open toward the top of the screen and I am trying to display an incoming message while keeping the scanner open so that if you are typing a message the incoming message will still display and you can resume typing where you left off. The only problem is that after the cursor moves to display the message and come back if I attempt to backspace some of the tests already in the scanner, the text is moved down and "^R" is displayed. Example:

```
>before cursor movement
```

```
>cursormoved^R
cursormove
```

How can I backspace some of the text without having this occur? Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.print(">");
                    String message = sc.nextLine();
                    SendMessages.send(message);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    String message = RecMessages.recMessage();
                    if (message != null) {
                        System.out.print("\0337"); // save cursor position
                        System.out.print("\n" + message);
                        System.out.print("\0338"); // restore saved curor position
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
```

Comment: All this has exactly nothing to do with the 'Java scanner', whatever that is here, and everything to do with whatever is displaying these alleged ANSI escape sequences. That sounds more like a text window than a 'scanner'. If you mean the same thing you are misusing standard terminology.

Comment: What kind of terminology would you suggest I use instead?